# Em que cenários vale a pena utilizar o ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Em que cenários o ElasticSearch é indicado como substituição das pesquisas em bases de dados ER ou NOSQL.

A principal dúvida é quando devo utilizar o elasticsearch, pois percebo em minhas aplicações que um postgresql 
ou mongodb já tem uma pesquisa satisfatória na maioria dos casos.

Se for possível, peço que cite alguns casos de uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No geral, para pesquisas relativamente simples o PostgreSQL é bom o suficiente, o que provavelmente deve ser o seu caso.

O elasticsearch se torna realmente relevante quando você precisa de features de busca mais complicadas, como por exemplo casamento complexo com os termos buscados ou usar analisadores de texto diferentes. Se você tem um volume muito grande de buscas, o elasticsearch também se comporta melhor que o PostgreSQL (usa menos hardware para o mesmo resultado).

Como exemplo, uma feature que uso no trabalho e acredito que seria difícil implementar com PostgreSQL é a possibilidade de [indexar sinônimos para palavras](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). Outra é a possibilidade rápida de encontrar [documentos similares](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) ou [sugerir buscas](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html) para o seu usuário.

Essas features enriquecem muito a busca de uma aplicação e são simples de implementar usando elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Podemos adicionar alguns casos de uso do Elastic e do Solr, que são produtos semelhantes. Ambas as ferramentas são buscadores de texto (text search), ou seja, são adequados quando as buscas do usuário são baseadas em campos de texto livre, como descrição ou nome.

Alguns exemplos que justificam a adoção de uma ferramenta de full text search:

- Exemplo 1: quais os registros que têm a palavra "televisão" em sua descrição.
- Exemplo 2: quais os registros que têm nome parecido com "marco", como marcos, marcus e marlos.
- Exemplo 3: quais os registros que têm as palavras "banco" e "dados" separadas por até 2 palavras de distância.
- Exemplo 4 (avançado): quais os registros que são parecidos com "star trek", como "battlestar galactica".

Um banco relacional até tem essas funcionalidades, mas nunca será tão eficiente quanto um buscador especializado (Elastic e Solr), porque é otimizado para buscas não textuais, que é exatamente o contrário de uma ferramenta de full text search.